# modifying look of a pre-installed WordPress widget

Tags: html, css, wordpress, widget

I need to modify look of a pre-installed widget on my wordpress blog. Need to add a border around a sidebar widget.

I have never modified any theme feature like this before and am not sure what to do.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier than it seems.

Step 1: make a backup of your theme and database before you change anything. Always do this.

Step 2: A good tool is using the firebug extension for the Firefox browser. This allows you to look at the code by pointing at it with the mouse-pointer.

Step 3: From there you can identify what specific elements you need to write new CSS rules for, or which CSS existing rules you need to alter.

Step 4: You would then add these new or updated rules to style.css in your wordpress editor.

If you can, post a link to the site and what item you want to change as well as how you want to change it.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

IN the admin panel of WordPress, under Appearance > Editor, you can edit the style.css file. You always want to have a backup in case you break something, but adding a border around something should be as simple as finding where it is styled and adding something like

```
border:1px solid black;
```